# Running a Perl script within a Stata .do file

Tags: perl, stata

Is it possible to execute a Perl script within a Stata .do file?

I have a Stata .do file in which I make some manipulations to the data set and arrange it in a certain way.  Then I have a Perl script in which I take one of the variables at this point, apply a Perl package to it, and make a transformation to one of the variables.  In particular, I use Perl's NYSIIS function, resulting in a very short script.  After this output is provided in Perl, I'd like to continue with some additional work in Stata.

Two alternatives that come to mind but that are less desirable are:

1. Write Stata code to do nysiis but I prefer to use Perl's built-in function.
2. `outsheet` and save the output from the Stata .do file as a .txt for Perl.  Then do the Perl script separately to get another .txt.  Then read in that .txt to Stata to a new .do file and resume.

Comment: yes, if it can run `batch/cmd` files :)

Comment: call your perl from `.bat`

Comment: Yes, but how precisely can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach number 2 is what I use to call other programs to operate on Stata data. As Nick says, Stata won't necessarily wait for your output, unless you ask it to. You first `outsheet` the text file, then call the Perl script from Stata using `!` to run something on the command line. Finally, have Stata periodically check for the result file, using a `while` loop and the `sleep` command so Stata isn't constantly checking.

```
outsheet using "perl_input.txt"
!perl my_perl_script.pl

while (1) {
    capture insheet using "perl_output.txt", clear
    if _rc == 0 continue, break
    sleep 10000
}

!rm perl_output.txt
```

Here, your formatted data is saved from Stata as `perl_input.txt`. Next, your Perl script is run from the command line, and using a `while` loop, Stata checks for the output every 10 seconds (`sleep` takes arguments in milliseconds). When it finds the output file, it breaks out of the `while` loop. The last line is a good idea so that when you re-use the code you don't run the risk of using the Perl output from the last run.

Comment: I edited the ' ' to " " above around filenames. If the filenames do not contain spaces, they are not needed but they never do any harm. Naturally the example presumes that files are in the same folder or directory as Stata is working in and can be generalized by specifying the folder or directory.

Comment: May I ask if I am understanding correctly?  It sounds like this solution is an improved version of the 2nd suggestion I had listed in the original posting?  It sounds like I first run the stata code and outsheet the first .txt.  I then run the perl code whilst stata is sleeping.  Shortly after the perl code is finished, Stata will stop sleeping, insheet the .txt file that perl spit out, and continue with the .do file?

Comment: That's broadly correct. The logic is that Stata is being told to `sleep` some more while there is no file to read in. The `capture` eats any error from `insheet` because the file does not exist.

Comment: Exactly as Nick said it. In my example, Stata will check for the file every 10 seconds. The sleep is just there to minimize Stata's CPU usage while the perl script is running. If running your perl script and saving the file doesn't take very long, you could have it sleep for only 1 second instead of 10. If it takes hours, you could have it only check every minute. The `if _rc == 0` line tells Stata to escape the while loop only if Stata successfully found the output file from perl. One danger here is that if your perl script is broken, stata will sleep forever (or until you `Ctrl-C`)

Comment: !perl my_perl_script actually opens up a command prompt window and runs the perl script?  what if i use something else to do perl?  in particular, i use cygwin.

Comment: Is !rm perl_output.txt supposed to delete the file?  That doesn't seem to be happening . . .

Comment: Yes, in my answer I stated that the intention of that command was so that future runs of your code don't use old versions of the perl output. `rm` is a unix command, and it appears that you're on windows, so use `del`. Also, as Nick stated, be careful that everything is in the right directory or that you are putting the complete file path to everything

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that although you can use the shell to call up something else, Stata is not going to wait for the results.

Start with `help shell` to see what is possible, but your #2 does sound easiest.